# Remover o último input digitado em um form com várias respostas

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um formulário de 10 respostas no qual a pessoa deve colocar apenas 3 respostas.

Se ela preencher mais de 3, o último `input` digitado deve ser apagado.

Segue o meu código:

Ele até que funciona, mas o problema é que não apaga o último `input` digitado dependendo da ordem que vou preencher.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="resposta1">
<input type="text" name="resposta2">
<input type="text" name="resposta3">
<input type="text" name="resposta4">
<input type="text" name="resposta5">
<input type="text" name="resposta6">
<input type="text" name="resposta7">
<input type="text" name="resposta8">
<input type="text" name="resposta9">
<input type="text" name="resposta10">
<input type="button" id="btn-bloco" value="Aperte">
```

**Javascript**

```
var totalDeRespostas = 10;

$("#btn-bloco").on("click",function(){
    var totalDeRespostasRespondidas = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i< totalDeRespostas;i++){
        if($("[name='resposta"+(i+1)+"']").val() != ""){                   
                totalDeRespostasRespondidas++;
                if(totalDeRespostasRespondidas > 3){
                    var aux = $("[name='resposta"+(i+1)+"']").val();
                    alert(aux);

                    $("[name='resposta"+(i+1)+"']").val("");
                }

        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olhando para o teu código sugiro fazeres de maneira mais limpa/simples:

```
var maxRespostas = 3;

$("#btn-bloco").on("click", function () {
    var respondidas = $('input[name^="resposta"]').filter(verificarValue);
    if (respondidas.length > maxRespostas) respondidas.slice(3).val('');
});

function verificarValue(i, input) {
    var value = input.value.split(' ').join('');
    return value;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4bq3mgvu/

Dessa maneira cada vez que fazes clique ele chama todos os inputs que têm nome começando com `resposta`:

```
$('input[name^="resposta"]')
```

depois filtra-os consoante o valor deixando os que estão respondidos numa coleção (`respondidas`). Para filtrar usei `input.value.split(' ').join('');` que no fundo apaga espaços em branco para ele não validar um input que pode ter um espaço em branco mas que na prática está vazio.

Aí verificas se os que estão preenchidos são mais que 3 com `if (respondidas.length > maxRespostas)`, e caso dê verdadeiro com o `.slice(3)` ele remove os 3 primeiros dessa coleção e apaga o valor dos restantes.